# Trying to read returned value from stored procedure always shows 0

Tags: sql-server, return-value

In SQL Server, I have an existing `Document_Add` stored procedure that works and returns a good `DocID` value (in Visual Studio vb code) and cannot change. Calling it like this in SQL:

```
EXEC @DocID = PADS2.dbo.Document_Add @SystemCode...
```

This runs the stored procedure, but `@DocID` is always 0 (whether declared as `INT` or `varchar`).

Expecting `@DocID` to be 2594631 or similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because `@DocID` is being assigned the value of the `RETURN` value from your procedure, and unless you've specifically defined a *different* `RETURN` value `0` denotes success. I suspect that what you actually want is an `OUTPUT` parameter. Can you share the definition of your procedure?

Comment: For brevity, here is the end of the SP:
 ...
 SELECT @Rslt = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000),@NewId)
 select @Rslt;
END

Comment: "returns a good DocID value" how? Using an output parameter, a return value, or `SELECT`? How is `@Rslt` defined? Why can't you show us the definition?

Comment: Those are `SELECT` statements, @MartMX , not a `RETURN`. It has *no relation* to the assignment to the variable `@DocID`. As i said, I suggest using an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: you should have RETURN statement at the end of your stored procedure
`RETURN(select @Rslt)`

Comment: Is `@DocID` declared as an OUTPUT parameter? In that case `DECLARE @DocID int; EXEC PADS2.dbo.Document_Add @SystemCode, @DocID OUTPUT; SELECT @DocID;`

Comment: BTW, don't a stored procedure return code (RETURN statement) to return data; Its purpose is to indicate success (zero) or error/warning (non-zero).

Comment: Calling the same SP in vb:
sDocid = DA.ExecScalarString(EXEC PADS2.DBO.[Document_Add] 'C', ...)
returns string '2680914'

Comment: Calling it from the code and sql is different. What do you really want to achieve why are you calling it in SQL?

Comment: To store some data in another table using the returned ID value from this call.

Comment: Will, if you can't change the stored procedure then you can just call 
`INSERT INTO [aTempTable] EXEC
PADS2.dbo.Document_Add @SystemCode...`

Answer (score 1):

<If this is not the place to follow up, please advise.>

Credit to rjs123431:

SQL SP that ends like this:

```
    ...
    SELECT @Rslt = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000),@NewId)
    select @Rslt;
END
```

Returns a string '2680914' in vb:

```
sDocid = DA.ExecScalarString(EXEC PADS2.DBO.[Document_Add] 'C', ...)
```

But returns 0 when called from SQL like this:

```
EXEC @DocID = PADS2.dbo.Document_Add @SystemCode...
```

This returns correct DocID (2680914) when using a Temp Table like this:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable EXEC PADS2.dbo.Document_Add @SystemCode...
set @sDocID = (SELECT DocID FROM @TempTable)
```

Comment: Also believe this would work: SET @sDocID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 0):

I always say RTFM - read the fine manual provided by microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
1 - Example D shows how to use input parameters.
2 - Example F show how to use output parameters.
```

Just remember, input and output parameters are scalar, not tables.

If you do need to input of a table look at Example G.

```
3 - Example G - how to pass a table value parameter
4 - Example B - return multiple result sets.
```

If you execute two SELECT statements in the procedure, you will have MARS (multiple active result sets).

By default, a procedure returns a value of zero.  It is typical used to indicate if the procedure was a success. You can code a non zero value to indicate an error.

Always read the docs!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement to read the manual. Every piece of technology comes with a 300 page manual. I've been working with SQL Server for about a month and haven't had time.  Over past 25 years of software development, I've worked on about 100 different technologies - all come with a 300 page manual. It's just not practical to read 30,000 pages of tech manuals.

Comment: But the answer was at the top of the page.  (:)->-< I usually hit MSDN (Microsoft Pages) to verify syntax when I don't know it off the top of my head.  Happy coding with SQL Server!

Comment: Hey, I value your guidance and thanks again. I do my due diligence to search for an answer, but nothing beats you experienced gurus here on stackoverflow. I have a working knowledge of SQL, but ramping up to be much better.